# Searching UTF8 special characters with a query using Google Bigquery

Tags: utf-8, google-bigquery

I have a query that is supposed to find the occurence of a special character in UTF8.

That is my query:

```
SELECT key FROM workspace.table1 WHERE key CONTAINS '\u266D'
```

However, I get the error message "Invalid string literal".

How can I properly use UTF8 characters in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery accepts UTF8 encoded input, so you should be able to pass the utf character in your query directly, rather than using the hex code:

```
SELECT count(*) from publicdata:samples.wikipedia where
title contains '♭'
```

returns `651`